# Does anyone know what "expected SCALAR, SEQUENCE-START, MAPPING-START, or ALIAS" means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, hash, scalar

Could anyone point me in the right direction, as when I save a small serialized hash via file upload to the database it works just fine, however when a large file comes along it errors out with;

```
expected SCALAR, SEQUENCE-START, MAPPING-START, or ALIAS
```

Im running Ruby 1.9.3po and rails 3.2.3, sQlite3. Database column is TEXT type with default limit. Using `serialize, :db_column, Hash` to save it correctly as a hash to the db.

I can't find anything decisive on google. Could it be something to do with how the database column is configured? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on the link here it could be a non UTF-8 character: https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/39

Comment: The files im trying to upload are text files with just letters in them, then converting into a hash, maybe the hash syntax is invalid UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

For me this error occured while working with delayed job. i had following in my rails model:

```
model MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  handle_asynchronously :enqueue

  def enqueue
  end

end
```

enqueue is reserved word in DJ, thus it was failing to fire and caused above error(and lot of headache until i found out what's going on)